# Is Joker (2019) part of the DC Extended Universe?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, joker-2019

I noticed that [*Joker* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_(2019_film)) does not appear on Wikipedia's list of [films belonging to the DC Extended Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe).

Is *Joker* part of the DC Extended Universe?

Comment: I downvoted for no apparent research. Copy-pasting the question's title into Google brings up several resources with a clear answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with what the Joker looks like in the DCEU?

Comment: @F1Krazy well there is more than 1 Joker in the comics so that argument may not have weight in the DCEU.

Comment: @Jenayah - And I plussed you for being the only stack overflow user on earth who has the decency and took the time to explain why you downvoted. Few things bother me more than downvotes with no explanation.

Answer (score 9):

No, *Joker* is intended as a standalone film and is not part of the DCEU. If anything it would be part of a new universe where various standalone films will be made but even then that sounds like more of an idea for future movies than an idea for a universe.

> "It's not really connected to that [DC Movie] Universe," Phillips told the crowd at a Q&A for Joker during the Toronto International Film Festival. "And it was really intentionally not. I mean the original idea when I went to [Warner Bros.] with the idea was not just about one movie, but about a label - sort of a side label to DC, where you can do these kind of character study, low-rent, low-budget movies, where you get a filmmaker to come in and do some deep dive into a character. So it was never meant to connect, so I don't see it connecting to anything in the future. I think this is just this movie, you know?"
>
> <sub>[comicbook, Joker Movie Director Clarifies Whether It Will Be Connected to the DC Cinematic Universe](https://comicbook.com/dc/2019/09/11/joker-dc-movie-universe-connections-todd-phillips-dceu/)</sub>

Comment: We saw the events leading to a new batman though, how will they deal (or not) with that?

Comment: @CptEric Everything I've seen so far is that it is a standalone film only so they won't be dealing with it. Whether or not the film's success changes that remains to be seen.